# Is there something called double "solution"? Or is it called a double "root"? There are some issues causing me a problem.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, terminology, quadratics

I encountered a Math problem that I don't quite understand.

> For what value of $b$ does the equation $ba^2 + 2a - 3 = 0$ have a single solution for $a$?

My reasoning is that both $-1/3$ and $0$ are correct answers, but $-1/3$ is apparently wrong (according to the answer key), despite making the equation have a single solution.

People told me that $-1/3$ will make the equation have a "double" solution and not a "single" solution. But is there actually something called a "double" solution?

A solution is a "value" that satisfies an equation. It is different from a root. $-1/3$ will make the equation have one "value" that satisfies it: $3$.

People told me that because the question asked for a "single" solution, it implies that the graph crosses (not just touches) the $x$-axis at $0$. They told me that "single" is different from "one" solution. But that is not really a function here. When I graph it, it is a vertical line. It is just an equation, and I don't think "single" is different from "one" solution. It is just a value. It has nothing to do with "roots".

Please clarify which of the opinions is correct and why.

Comment: the context ought to specify what is wanted, but generally speaking roots are counted with multiplicity, so $(x-c)^n$ has $n$ roots, all of which equal $c$.

Comment: I've never heard the term "double solution," so far as I can recall.  I would say $b=-\frac13$ is a valid answer, as well as $b=0$.  This is just a matter of terminology, and really not worth spending much time on.

Comment: I also agree that $b=-1/3$ is a valid answer. (I'd give more-nuanced phrasing if multiplicity were to be considered an issue.) It's possible that the solution key is in error. (These things happen.) ... That said, the equation seems tailor-made to suggest that $b=-1/3$ is at least *candidate*, so it's also possible the author is making a point about why it should be rejected. Yet, if the text or source material doesn't discuss the matter (eg, providing explicit guidance about when multiplicity (ahem) *counts*), then there's no way for us to know the author's point or to assess it.

Comment: I agree that $-1/3$ and $0$ are both solutions to the question. Whoever wrote the question is probably trying to make a clever point about the multiplicity of roots but, as others have said, this is mere pedantry. You are fine - don't worry about it.